# How can I add Linkedin login to my website using Django allauth?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-allauth

I am using frontend React Js and Backend Django. I need to setup login with LinkedIn and Facebook. So I am trying to achieve by using django allauth. I am new to Django so I am confusing the how to setup. Can I use allauth to achieve my requirements or what can be the best way to achieve and how?